# Can't read input?

Tags: java, input, error-handling

Hi I have the following code and I keep getting an error when reading the input. I've tried to figure this out however I have had no success in doing so. My input is

```
5
8 1
1 4
8 8
7 15
4 20
```

My error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at trapped.main(trapped.java:12)
```

My code is

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class trapped {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner("C:/usaco.txt");

        int index = sc.nextInt();

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to create a  [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) object that points to your text file and construct your `Scanner` from that. Right now your `Scanner` object is reading from the path you passed it, and `"C"` is not an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Scanner(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.lang.String%29) variant gives you a scanner which reads the *string,* not the file that the string refers to. You can see that with the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner("C:/usaco.txt");
        String str = sc.next();
        System.out.print(str);
    }
}
```

which outputs the file *name* `C:/usaco.txt` rather than the file *content.*

If you want to read from a file specified by the string, you'll need a file object, something like:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("C:/usaco.txt"));
```

as per:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("/home/pax/xyzzy.txt"));
            int ivar = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print(ivar);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a file object first:
File file = new File("C:/usaco.txt");
and then 
Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);